# solving trig equation $4\cos(3\cdot \theta)=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given the equation $r^2 =4\cos(3 \theta)$ how can I find the solutions when $r=0$? The solutions should be: $\pm \frac{\pi}{6}$, $\pm \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\pm \frac{5 \pi}{6}$. I'm not sure where they got the $\pm$ from and how they found all the solutions, I've only managed to find $\frac{\pi}{6}$ by dividing $\cos^{-1}(0)$ by $3$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$4 \cos 3\theta = 0$ means $\cos 3\theta = 0$.

In general, $\cos x = 0$ means $x = \pm \frac \pi 2, \pm\frac{3\pi}2, \pm\frac{5\pi}2, \dots$

In our case, $\cos 3\theta = 0$ means $3\theta = \pm \frac\pi2, \pm\frac{3\pi}2, \pm\frac{5\pi}2, \dots$.

Solve that last equation there for $\theta$ (by basically dividing both sides by $3$.  You'll get infinitely many solutions.  It looks like they want you to keep your answers in the interval $-\pi \le \theta < \pi$, so make sure to exclude solutions that aren't in that interval.

Comment: why the interval -pi<thetha <pi? and also how came you get + - for all the solutions?

Comment: Because $4\cos3\theta = 0$ has infinitely many solutions and you only gave finitely many.  And all of them are in the interval $-\pi \le \theta < \pi$.  The $\pm$ just comes from basic properties of trig and the unit circle.  $\cos \frac\pi2 = 0$, and $\cos \left(-\frac\pi2\right) = 0$, etc.

Comment: ok I see but the one thing that got me a bit confusied, isnt this just a bunch of the same angles listed over and over again? isnt -pi/2 the same as 3pi/2 ?

Comment: They aren't the same because they aren't equal.  But they are **coterminal** because they intersect the unit circle at the same point (and have the same vertex, which is the origin, and the same initial  ray, which is the positive $x$-axis).  It's a subtle distinction but it's important to keep in mind that "same" and "coterminal" aren't the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos(x)=0 \iff x=\pi/2+\pi k,\quad k\in \mathbb Z.$$
In your case you thushave to solve $3x=\pi/2+\pi k\iff x=\pi/6+\pi k/3.$

Now keep only the $k$'s such that $x\in[-\pi,\pi).$

Comment: That's sine, not cosine.

Comment: yeah. I must be tired. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Yep, been there.  Am there now actually, as I had to stop and think for a bit "...is it sine?"

Comment: haha! Yeah, such mistakes are too easy to make.